# No HDMI 2.0 output from NUC6i7KYK on 16.04 -- fixes?

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, intel-nuc

Intel NUC6i7KYK with Iris Pro 580 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 .

Mini-DP from NUC to DP 1.2 on monitor works great (4K @ 60Hz).

HDMI from NUC to HDMI 2.0 on monitor shows the POST at boot (booting from installation on USB as well as SSD), shows grub, then shows the Ubuntu logo with the little progress dots beneath it, then shows the purple screen, then ... monitor shows no signal.

When hooking up to my TV, which does not have HDMI 2.0, it works fine.

When using a mini DP from the NUC adapted to HDMI on the monitor, it works fine (though only 30Hz as expected).

When running a windows installation, it works fine.

The driver shows that it is recognizing it is Iris Pro 580 (from the system info screen in ubuntu).

So the problem config is:  HDMI 2.0 source (NUC), HDMI 2.0 monitor (LG 27UD68), Ubuntu.

Any ideas?  I've been through quite a few iterations to narrow it down this far, but the driver seems right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same problem myself.  If I downgrade my kernel to 4.2, it comes back.  But 4.4 & 4.7 (I tried the latest released kernel to see if it was fixed), and no HDMI.  Yes, this helps me rationalize a 4K monitor, but jeepers, it would be nice if HDMI just... y'know, worked.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply.  I thought maybe I was going crazy, but it's such a new machine that I'm not surprised there are issues.  I'm very surprised to find that 4.2 works while 4.4+ does not, but glad to know it all the same.  I returned the machine and went with a good ol' ATX form factor box I had sitting in my closet that had two PCIe cards, and it does 4k just fine (running 2.0x scaling for super crisp text).  Thanks again for your response. Since this is still unresolved, I'm leaving it open but have upvoted your response.

Comment: @Josh I'd say it's a solution given current climate, fully warrants to be marked as correct

Comment: Well, this still doesn't work in 2018 :/